# Is there more concise way to check if variable has typeof number?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm currently using this kind of validation to check if multiple inputs have type `number`:

```
if (typeof a === "number" &&
    typeof b === "number" &&
    typeof c === "number"
) {
    // do something
}
```

Can this be written in some other way?

P.S. I can extract this into helper method or to some variable to boost readability of if statement, but want to know if there is some native way to do the same thing -  `typeof varName === 'number'`.

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: You could use an array with every `[a, b, c].every(val => typeof val === "number")`

Comment: If this is a recurring conditional check then you can consider using ternary operator and creating a variable for the boolean result. Otherwise, there isn't much you can do about it. For ternary operator: `const condition = typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number' && typeof c === 'number'`. Now you can use this in conditional flow: `if(condition) { //... }`

Answer (score -1):

In case you have more variables, you could use an array and loop through them:

```
let arr = [a, b, c] // or more ...
let flag = false
let i = 0
while (!flag) {
  if (typeof arr[i] !== "number") {
     flag = true
  }
}
```

After the loop finishes, you should check if the flag variable is set to true or false; if it's false, then all of them were numbers, if not, then at least one is not a nummber.